# How to add Data to Custom table in database using model in magento 2.3.5

Tags: database, ajax, model, resource-model, magento2.3.5-p1

I am created one form for contact and i want to insert form data into custom table in database in magento 2.3.5
so can anyone have idea about it then please send me solution.

```
<?php
namespace Aspl\Contact\Controller\Ajax;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Aspl\Contact\Model\ContactFactory;

class ContDet extends Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    protected $_resultJsonFactory;
    
    protected $contactFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context, ContactFactory $contactFactory, PageFactory $resultPageFactory, JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory)
    {
       $this->contactFactory = $contactFactory;
       $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
       $this->_resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
       return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->_resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
                
        try {
                
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams('data');

                $model = $this->contactFactory->create();

                //save data to variables
                $model->setName($data['name']);
                $model->setContact($data['contact']);
                $model->setAddress($data['address']);
                $model->setComments($data['comments']);

                $model->save();
     
                $response = [
                    'errors' => false,
                    'message' => __('Please Wait our Service team can contact you as soon as possible.')
                ];

            } 
            catch (\Exception $e) 
            {
                $response = [
                    'errors' => true,
                    'message' => __('Invalid Contact Details.').$e->getMessage()
                ];
            }
            return $result;
    }
}
```

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will help you to save data in custom table, please [refer this blog](https://code.vky.co.in/insert-data-custom-table-using-resource-model-magento-2/)

Comment: I want to add data using controller and using model,resource model

Comment: your solution is not working

Comment: what is error are you facing ??

Comment: data is not ging to save in database

Comment: I can send my controller please reply where is the mistake

Comment: okay first you can check  when you form submit data is pass properly?
using browser console you can trace controller request and data also

Comment: please see my question in that i have put my controller file

Comment: in database custom table are you created something like "id", "entity_id" with primary key, Auto increment ?  && also check $this->getRequest()->getParams('data'); give proper data using log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109872/discussion-between-chandresh-chauhan-and-deep-shah).